# For how many values of x will n + x = n XOR x when n and x are whole numbers and n>=x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, xor

Note:The contest is over.I just want to know other way to solve this

```
n = int(input())
if n == 0:
    print('1')
else:
    print(1<<(str(bin(n)).count('0') - 1))
```

Chef has studied 2- bit Binary Adder in his Digital Logic Design class. He is amazed by the XOR operator and he believes that a + b = a xor b, where a and b are whole numbers and xor is Bitwise XOR operator.

Chef's teacher's favorite number is n. Chef's teacher is in angry mood and he gives Chef a whole number x (x <= n) and asks Chef to compute n + x to test his Binary Addition understanding. Chef answers n xor x.

Input
A single integer n.

sample input:0
sample output:1

sample input:5
sample output:2

Comment: Just to clarify, `x ^ n` is `x XOR n`? not `pow(x, n)`?

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald   Yeah,I know that

Comment: Why 1 for input 0?

Comment: @user2357112 for n=0 there is only one value of x which satisfies the condition which is x=0

Comment: Are we taking x<n or x<=n? The title and body seem contradictory.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm sorry and i have edited the question

Comment: @user2357112 it doesn't matter as n^x != n+x when n == x

Comment: @Demonking28 maybe I'm missing something in my calculations but this solution seems to be off by one in all the examples I've tried so far. My solution: `print(pow(2, (str(bin(n)).count('0')-1))-1)`

Comment: @alfasin: It matters for n=x=0.

Comment: That's why we discussed the edge-case of 0 and that's why it's handled separately.

Comment: Given the definition of addition, `(n + x) == (n ^ x)` if, and only if, there are no carries. Or in other words, `(n & x) == 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested solution:

```
n = int(input())
if n == 0:
    print('1')
else:
    print(pow(2, (str(bin(n)).count('0')-1)))
```

when n = 0 it prints 1 and when n = 5 it outputs 2 and etc.

It's doing the same thing the solution above is doing: counting the number of zeros, `k`, in the binary representation of `n`, ignoring the leading zero, and returns 2<sup>k</sup> as an answer because any integer `x` that has any number of these bits turned on - will qualify for `n ^ x == n + x`